# How do you programmatically update a tag using the TaggingRules mechanism?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, gui-construction

Consider the following simple front-end code:

```
cdflocation = 
  CurrentValue[
   EvaluationNotebook, {TaggingRules, 
    "cdfpath"}];(* load any previously used file path *)

CreatePalette[{
  TextCell["\n1. Choose any file for analysis?", Bold, Blue, 16],

  Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[cdflocation]], Spacer[20], 
    Dynamic[cdflocation]
    }],

  Button["Go!",
   If[Head[cdflocation] === Symbol,
    Print["not ready"],
    (Print["tag should update now"];
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook, {TaggingRules, "cdfpath"}] = 
      cdflocation)]](* trouble spot here *)

  }]
```

---

I want to using the TaggingRules functionality to store file pathways with a notebook.

When the user selects a new file with the Browse button, and then selects the Go button, I would like the tag to be updated so users can load the notebook into a fresh kernel/session and always have the most recently selected file pathway available.

While I can manually reset the tag, it seems the code marked (* trouble spot here *) does nothing.

Questions:

A.  Any idea why my approach is not working?

B.  Any thoughts on a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Kuba  Tired eyes.  Yes, your observation about [] after EvaluationNotebook is certainly appreciated.  That explains why the notebook kept "beeping" at me.  Unfortunately, the primary issue still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EvaluationNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationNotebook.html) gives the palette Notebook itself; try using [`InputNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputNotebook.html) instead:

```
CreatePalette[{TextCell["\n1. Choose any file for analysis?", Bold, Blue, 16], 
  Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[cdflocation]], Spacer[20], Dynamic[cdflocation]}], 
  Button["Go!", 
   If[Head[cdflocation] === Symbol, Print["not ready"], (Print["tag should update now"];
     CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "cdfpath"}] = cdflocation)]]
```

Comment: Problem solved.  I don't know what I would do without StackExchange and the kind folks that share their expertise and time.  Thank you!

Comment: @Todd I'm glad I could help. :-)